# Logic behind the direction of coefficient in generalized estimating equation

Tags: regression, inference, regression-coefficients, computational-statistics, generalized-estimating-equations

I am not familiar with statistics and thus nor am I familiar with the methodological reasoning behind it so can someone please explain the reasoning behind the following results:

I have an outcome (let`s say hypertention) and another outcome (let`s say blood pleasure) which both are related to the cardiovascular health. Can someone tell me what could be the potential reasoning behind this:

for age I get positive coefficient for hypertension but I get negative for blood pleasure? Is this normal? Given that both outcomes are measures of cardiovascular health? Or this is raising a flag about something that I am missing when running gee on my data?